# pmap data format (Julia 1.1.0)

Tags: output, julia, pmap

I have a function which I run using pmap. I would like the output to be a vector - p - whose entries are the output of each iteration run parallel. For illustration, the code is as below:

```
@everywhere function addo(mc,mcf)

p = zeros(Int64,mcf) ;

p[mc] = mc ;

return p 

end 

pmap(mc -> addo(mc,mcf),1:1:mcf) ;
```

The output I get is

```
100-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
 ⋮                                                                
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100]
```

Instead, I need something like this, p = [1,2,3,4,...,100];

How do I get the output in the desired format?

Comment: When I have more than one return value of different types - Array{Int64,N},SimpleDiGraph{Int64},Bool - and the function is run 5 times. How can I access the second element(SimpleDiGraph) of the the 3rd run ? p[1/2/3] only return the 1st,2nd or 3rd element of the 1st run and  p[3,2] returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

`pmap`, similar to `map`, applies your transformation function,`mc -> addo(mc, mcf)`, to each element in the collection `1:1:mcf`. The problem in your code is that for each element in the collection you are creating a new vector of size `mcf` and the overall result becomes an *array of the arrays you create in each transformation*, whereas what you want is the result of `pmap` to be of size `mcf`. Therefore, for each element in the collection, you should return only one element. `pmap` already gives you a collection grouping the results of each transformation.

```
@everywhere function addo(mc)
    return mc
end 

p = pmap(mc -> addo(mc), 1:1:mcf)
```

This will give you `p = [1,2,3,4,...,100]`.